# Проблема с сериализацией nullable type свойств

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, сериализация

К проекту подключен внешний Service Reference. Сгенерированный код в Reference.cs содержит свойства `int` и `DateTime`, помеченные как `Nullable`. Например:

```
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<int> idType {
        get {
            return this.idTypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.idTypeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("idType");
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что после сериализации эти свойства отсутствуют в теле XML-запроса. Пример кода с отправкой запроса:

```
        using (SingleFormatServiceClient c = new SingleFormatServiceClient())
        {
            AuthData auth = new AuthData()
            {
                login = "login",
                password = "pass"
            };

            GroupRequestData requestData = new GroupRequestData();

            ConnectorCode connectorCode = new ConnectorCode()
            {
                connectorCode = "0",
                subRequestCode = new[] { "1" }
            };

            PersonRequestData personRequestData = new PersonRequestData();

            personRequestData.idNum = "757496";
            personRequestData.idSeries = "9823";
            personRequestData.idType = 21;
            personRequestData.consentEndDate = DateTime.ParseExact("05.08.2020", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            personRequestData.issueLocation = "МОСКВА";

            requestData.personParam = new[] { personRequestData };
            requestData.connectorCodes = new[] { connectorCode };

            ProcessRequestOut resp = c.groupRequest(auth, requestData);
        }
```

Запрос успешно отправляется. Все стринговые свойства (`idNum`, `idSeries`, `issueLocation`) в запросе присутствуют. `idType` и `consentEndDate` нет (вообще их нет в структуре xml). Пытаясь разобраться, в отладчике увидел, что эти свойства возвращаются не как свойства, а как поля с ограниченным доступом (?):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по всему, в этом и проблема. Если в сгенерированном классе сервис-референса убрать `Nullable` тип, то свойство возвращается в своём нормальном виде, но возникают другие проблемы при вызове сервиса.
Возможно ли как-то обойти проблему, желательно без внесения изменений в сгенерированный код? Доступа к исходному коду сервиса нет. Благодарю за любую помощь и идеи.